# HTML select options are not disabled/enabled on button click as they should Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html-select

I'm trying to disable options on my select element in my HTML page using javascript DOM.

On button click a function should disable every option in the select, and another button should enable them again.

The problem is that the first option is never disabled and also on button click the events aren't triggered. I can't figure out what is the problem even if i tried for hours.

This is my select and the buttons:

```
<select name="tempoTest" 
                          id="tempoTest1" 
                          class="input-dimension select2 tempoTest" 
                          required="true" 
                          style="padding:0.8%;">
                <option value="days">Giorni</option>
                <option value="hours">Ore</option>
                <option value="minutes">Minuti</option>
            </select>

<button type="button" class="btn-default btn-edit" name="edit1" id="edit1" onclick="editInput()">Edit </button> 
<button type="button" class="btn-default btn-edit" name="annulla1" id="annulla1" onclick="annullaEdit()" style="margin-left:6%">Annulla </button>
```

This is what should happen when the page is loaded (default):

```
var time = "minutes";

var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); //per evitare conflitti con altre librerie
$j("#tempoTest1").val(time).trigger('change');
document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = true;
document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = true;
document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = true;

document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = true;
```

These are the functions to disable and enable ("editInput()" should enable every option and "annullaEdit" should disable them)

```
function editInput(){
    var tempo = "hours" //value from DB




    $j("#tempoTest1").val(tempo).trigger('change');
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = false;   
    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = false;

}

function annullaEdit(){
    var tempo = <?php echo json_encode($time)?>;

    $j("#tempoTest1").val(tempo).trigger('change');             
    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = true;

    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = true;

}
```

Is there a reason why the functions aren't working properly and the first option is never disabled?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML, not PHP source code. And do you get any messages in your browser's console window?

Comment: What is `$j()` ?

Comment: jQuery caused some conflicts so i changed $ in $j, I updated the question with "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();"

Comment: in my console i don't get any message

Comment: the PHP value is because i need to select another option that is not necessarily the first option in the list. But this causes a problem because the first option in the select element is never disabled

Comment: You should put chosen values for the `tempo` and `time` variables instead of "php" so we can have a working snippet here. :)

Comment: ok i will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think is a working snippet:

```js
// This is what should happen when the page is loaded (default):
var time = "minutes";

var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); //per evitare conflitti con altre librerie
$j("#tempoTest1").val(time).trigger('change');
/*document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = true;
document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = true;
document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = true;*/
document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = true;


// These are the functions to disable and enable ("editInput()" should enable every option and "annullaEdit" should disable them)
function editInput() {
  var tempo = "hours" //value from DB

  $j("#tempoTest1").val(tempo).trigger('change');
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = false;
  /*document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = false;*/
}

function annullaEdit() {
  var tempo = "hours";

  $j("#tempoTest1").val(tempo).trigger('change');
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = true;
  /*document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = true;*/

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="tempoTest" id="tempoTest1" class="input-dimension select2 tempoTest" required="true" style="padding:0.8%;">
  <option value="days">Giorni</option>
  <option value="hours">Ore</option>
  <option value="minutes">Minuti</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn-default btn-edit" name="edit1" id="edit1" onclick="editInput()">Edit </button>
<button type="button" class="btn-default btn-edit" name="annulla1" id="annulla1" onclick="annullaEdit()" style="margin-left:6%">Annulla </button>
```

As it doesn't change the user experience, I've changed the enabling and disabling of the options to comments.

Please comment to explain what is not working or what you want to modify, if necessary.

Comment: Hello, sadly i couldn't figure out the solution because it should clearly work as in te examples, but it doesn't. I decided to find an alternative solution to avoid doing this. I'm really thankful for your answer and because it found the solution, i will declare it as best answer. Maybe my problem was more extended since my real HTML page is very long.

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script>
            function editInput() {
                //var tempo = "hours" //value from DB
                //$j("#tempoTest1").val(tempo).trigger('change');
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = false;
            }

            function annullaEdit() {
                //var tempo = <?php echo json_encode($time)?>;
                //$j("#tempoTest1").val(tempo).trigger('change');
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[0].disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[1].disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("tempoTest1").options[2].disabled = true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="tempoTest"
                id="tempoTest1"
                class="input-dimension select2 tempoTest"
                required="true"
                style="padding:0.8%;">
            <option value="days">Giorni</option>
            <option value="hours">Ore</option>
            <option value="minutes">Minuti</option>
        </select>

        <button type="button" class="btn-default btn-edit" name="edit1" id="edit1" onclick="editInput()">Edit </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn-default btn-edit" name="annulla1" id="annulla1" onclick="annullaEdit()" style="margin-left:6%">Annulla </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```